# Convert JSONP to JSON with Spring RestTemplate

Tags: java, json, spring, rest

I have a service which downloads a JSONP file containing JSON and processes it. I am trying to do it in the correct Spring way but I have not found any tutorials for this particular scenario (though there are plenty about converting json to jsonp).

To illustrate the problem, lets say that I am hitting the following url: "https://www.example.com/file.jsonp" which contains the following:

```
callback(
 { 
   "field1": "value1", 
   "field2": "value2"
 }
);
```

In order to process the JSON, I need to remove the callback (which I am currently doing manually with substring). Is there any recommended way in Spring how to get POJO directly from this JSONP file?

Let's assume that I only have the annotated pojo and just want to call:

```
  RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
  Pojo pojo = restTemplate.getForObject(url, Pojo.class);
```

At the moment, it gives me the following exception:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class com.berrycloud.blueberry.monitor.price.model.OnDemandPricePOJO] and content type [application/javascript]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
...
```

Thank you for any tips. I hope this is not a duplicate.

Comment: Did you have `Jackson 1` or `Jackson 2` in your classpath? As you need this for the default JSON `HttpMessageConverter`

Comment: I have Jackson 2.4.4 in my classpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that there is no built in converter for JSONP objects as described in my question. I ended up manually removing the beginning and end of the string and then converting the rest into standard JSON.

Another possibility is to implement a custom `MessageConvertor` and preprocess the JSONP object there.

A nice tutorial on how to write custom message convertors can be found [HERE](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-httpmessageconverter-rest).